# VBA Form Results Formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I am working to build a basic form in excel to speed up some of the accounting process at my uncles company. However I need to have a different format. The top line is what my current code creates however it needs to be like row 5 onwards so they can upload it to Quickbooks.

[image]

What changes do I need to make to this Macro:

```
Sub Invoice_Save()
Dim InvRow As Long, LastItemRow As Long, InvItenRow As Long, TotalItems As Long
Dim InvNumb As String

With Sheet1
    If .Range("J4").Value = Empty Or .Range("I6").Value = Empty Then
        MsgBox "Please Make sure to enter and Inovice # and Date"
    End If
    InvRow = Sheet2.Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Invoice Row
    InvNumb = .Range("J4").Value 'Invoice Number
    Sheet2.Range("A" & InvRow).Value = Range("I6").Value 'Date
    Sheet2.Range("B" & InvRow).Value = InvNumb 'InvNumb
    Sheet2.Range("C" & InvRow).Value = Range("I8").Value 'Customer
    Sheet2.Range("D" & InvRow).Value = Range("I10").Value 'Provider
    Sheet2.Range("E" & InvRow).Value = Range("I12").Value 'Service1
    Sheet2.Range("F" & InvRow).Value = Range("I16").Value 'Service2
    Sheet2.Range("G" & InvRow).Value = Range("I20").Value 'Service3
    Sheet2.Range("H" & InvRow).Value = Range("I24").Value 'Service4
    Sheet2.Range("I" & InvRow).Value = Range("I28").Value 'Service5
    Sheet2.Range("J" & InvRow).Value = Range("I32").Value 'Service6
    Sheet2.Range("K" & InvRow).Value = Range("I36").Value 'Service7
    Sheet2.Range("L" & InvRow).Value = Range("I40").Value 'Service8
    Sheet2.Range("M" & InvRow).Value = Range("I44").Value 'Service9
    Sheet2.Range("N" & InvRow).Value = Range("L14").Value 'Quantity1
    Sheet2.Range("O" & InvRow).Value = Range("L18").Value 'Quantity2
    Sheet2.Range("P" & InvRow).Value = Range("L22").Value 'Quantity3
    Sheet2.Range("Q" & InvRow).Value = Range("L26").Value 'Quantity4
    Sheet2.Range("R" & InvRow).Value = Range("L30").Value 'Quantity5
    Sheet2.Range("S" & InvRow).Value = Range("L34").Value 'Quantity6
    Sheet2.Range("T" & InvRow).Value = Range("L38").Value 'Quantity7
    Sheet2.Range("U" & InvRow).Value = Range("L42").Value 'Quantity8
    Sheet2.Range("V" & InvRow).Value = Range("L46").Value 'Quantity9
    Sheet2.Range("W" & InvRow).Value = Range("I48").Value 'Notes
   
 
End With

   
End Sub
```

I tried a couple of things like creating a new variable line InvRow for columns but it did not work.

Comment: this question is too broad for S.O. Can you please show us what you tried and explain how it fails to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Please see: [mcve]

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Please read the question. He shows his code. The question is fairly understandable. It is very discouraging if a new member gets such comments.

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Invoice_Save()
    
    Dim r As Long, i As Long, serv, qu
    
    With Sheet1
        If .Range("J4").Value = Empty Or .Range("I6").Value = Empty Then
            MsgBox "Please Make sure to enter and Invoice # and Date"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    With Sheet2
        With .UsedRange
           r = .Row + .Rows.Count   'Invoice Row
        End With
        .Range("A" & r).Value = Sheet1.Range("I6").Value 'Date
        .Range("B" & r).Value = Sheet1.Range("J4").Value 'InvNumb
        .Range("C" & r).Value = Sheet1.Range("I8").Value 'Customer
        .Range("D" & r).Value = Sheet1.Range("I10").Value 'Provider
        .Range("W" & r).Value = Sheet1.Range("I48").Value 'Notes
        
        ' Service and Quantity 1-9
        For i = 0 To 8
            serv = Sheet1.Range("I12").Offset(i * 4) 'Service i+1
            qu = Sheet1.Range("L14").Offset(i * 4) ' Quantity i+1
            If Len(serv) > 0 Or Len(qu) > 0 Then
               If i > 0 Then r = r + 1
               .Range("E" & r).Value = serv
               .Range("F" & r).Value = qu
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking that I should propose a way that you can intervene in some changes that will happen if, for example, the position of some fields of the invoice changes or adding one more field, without necessarily knowing a lot of things from programming. All you will need in simple cases is to add the fields to match. So I made another Sub where you have a visual matching of the fields. Also there is a variable gapBetweenInvoices you can set as value the gap rows between the records. I set it to 1 for better presentation results.

```
Sub Invoice_Save()
   Dim src As Range, dst As Range, r As Range, lastUsedCell As Range
   Dim srcCellsCnt As Long, freeRow As Long, c As Long, sv() As Variant, cnt As Long
   'MODIFY gapBetweenInvoices to have empty rows between records
   Const maxServices = 9, gapBetweenInvoices = 1   'gap one row
   
   ' This way there is a visual one-to-one mapping of the cells from the source sheet
   ' to the destination sheet. This way it will be easy to make any modification that may arise.
   ' CAN CHANGE THE FORMAT OR ADD MORE FIELDS... CHANGING ONLY THE NEXT TWO LINES OF CODE
   Set src = Sheet1.Range("I6, J4, I8, I10, I12, I16, I20, I24, I28, I32, I36, I40, I44, L14, L18, L22, L26, L30, L34, L38, L42, L46, L48")
   Set dst = Sheet2.Range("A1, B1, C1, D1,  E1,  E2,  E3,  E4,  E5,  E6,  E7,  E8,  E9,  F1,  F2,  F3,  F4,  F5,  F6,  F7,  F8,  F9,  W1")
   ' check fir equal number of cells in source and destination ranges
   srcCellsCnt = src.CountLarge
   If srcCellsCnt <> dst.CountLarge Then
      MsgBox ("Mismatch in the number of source - destination cells")
      Exit Sub
   End If
   With Sheet1
      If .Range("J4").Value = vbNullString Or .Range("I6").Value = vbNullString Then
          MsgBox "Please Make sure to enter and Inovice # and Date"
          Exit Sub
      End If
   End With       
   ' find the next free cell to write a record.
   ' try to find the free position checking ONLY columns A , E and F
   ' I could use "UsedRange" but there would be a commitment
   ' not to write anything anywhere eg a note which would exceed the record limit
   With Me.UsedRange
      Set lastUsedCell = Me.Cells(.row + .rows.CountLarge - 1, 1).End(xlUp)
      For cnt = 1 To maxServices
         If lastUsedCell.Offset(cnt, 4).Value2 = vbNullString And lastUsedCell.Offset(cnt, 5).Value2 = vbNullString Then
            ' found free cell, calculate the row to use as offset for destination range
            freeRow = lastUsedCell.row + cnt - 1 + gapBetweenInvoices
            Exit For
         End If
      Next
   End With
   
   ' if freeRow = 0 the sheet is FULL
   If freeRow = 0 Then
      MsgBox "sheet2 FULL!!! no other invoices can be added."
      Exit Sub
   End If
   
   ' copy source values in 1D array
   ReDim sv(1 To srcCellsCnt)
   cnt = 1
   For Each r In src
      sv(cnt) = r.Value2   'Trim(r.Value2)
      cnt = cnt + 1
   Next
   
   ' write values from 1D array to destination cells
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   cnt = 1
   For Each r In dst.Offset(freeRow)
      r.Value2 = sv(cnt)
      cnt = cnt + 1
   Next
End Sub
```

Try this: (first attempt)

```
Sub Invoice_Save()
   Dim InvRow As Long, InvRowTmp As Long, LastItemRow As Long, InvItenRow As Long, TotalItems As Long
   Dim InvNumb As String
   
   With Sheet1
      If .Range("J4").value = Empty Or .Range("I6").value = Empty Then
         MsgBox "Please Make sure to enter and Inovice # and Date"
      End If
      InvRow = Sheet2.Range("A999999").End(xlUp).row + 1 ' Invoice Row
      InvRowTmp = Sheet2.Range("E999999").End(xlUp).row + 1 ' Invoice Row
      If InvRowTmp > InvRow Then InvRow = InvRowTmp
      InvRowTmp = Sheet2.Range("F999999").End(xlUp).row + 1 ' Invoice Row
      If InvRowTmp > InvRow Then InvRow = InvRowTmp
      InvNumb = .Range("J4").value ' Invoice Number
      Sheet2.Range("A" & InvRow).value = .Range("I6").value ' Date
      Sheet2.Range("B" & InvRow).value = InvNumb ' InvNumb
      Sheet2.Range("C" & InvRow).value = .Range("I8").value ' Customer
      Sheet2.Range("D" & InvRow).value = .Range("I10").value ' Provider
      Sheet2.Range("E" & InvRow).value = .Range("I12").value ' Service1
      Sheet2.Range("E" & InvRow + 1).value = .Range("I16").value ' Service2
      Sheet2.Range("E" & InvRow + 2).value = .Range("I20").value ' Service3
      Sheet2.Range("E" & InvRow + 3).value = .Range("I24").value ' Service4
      Sheet2.Range("E" & InvRow + 4).value = .Range("I28").value ' Service5
      Sheet2.Range("E" & InvRow + 5).value = .Range("I32").value ' Service6
      Sheet2.Range("E" & InvRow + 6).value = .Range("I36").value ' Service7
      Sheet2.Range("E" & InvRow + 7).value = .Range("I40").value ' Service8
      Sheet2.Range("E" & InvRow + 8).value = .Range("I44").value ' Service9
      Sheet2.Range("F" & InvRow).value = .Range("L14").value ' Quantity1
      Sheet2.Range("F" & InvRow + 1).value = .Range("L18").value ' Quantity2
      Sheet2.Range("F" & InvRow + 2).value = .Range("L22").value ' Quantity3
      Sheet2.Range("F" & InvRow + 3).value = .Range("L26").value ' Quantity4
      Sheet2.Range("F" & InvRow + 4).value = .Range("L30").value ' Quantity5
      Sheet2.Range("F" & InvRow + 5).value = .Range("L34").value ' Quantity6
      Sheet2.Range("F" & InvRow + 6).value = .Range("L38").value ' Quantity7
      Sheet2.Range("F" & InvRow + 7).value = .Range("L42").value ' Quantity8
      Sheet2.Range("F" & InvRow + 8).value = .Range("L46").value ' Quantity9
      Sheet2.Range("W" & InvRow).value = .Range("I48").value ' Notes
   End With
End Sub
```